# Reduce number of lines by reusing code and passing member names to run tests on

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two car objects from the same class and a list of cars.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

cars = []

car1 = Car()
car1.color = 'black'
cars.append(car1)
car2 = Car()
car2.engine = 'V8'
cars.append(car2)
```

I also have two functions that are designed to remove object from `cars` if match.

```
def rm_car_color(c):
    for car_n in cars:
        try:
            if car_n.color == c.color:
                cars.remove(car_n)
        except Exception, err:
            pass

def rm_car_engine(c):
    for car_n in cars:
        try:
            if car_n.engine == c.engine:
                cars.remove(car_n)
        except Exception, err:
            pass
```

As you can see, they are practically identical. What I want is to be able to pass which members to check to the function so that I can remove one of these two functions and only have one that handles both in Python 2.6.6. Is this possible?

This code is only for explanation. The code I am working on has many of these remove functions (8 in total) and I would significantly reduce the number of lines if I could do this.

Comment: Also, if anyone has a better topic name for this post, please change it. I struggled with finding a good sentence.

Comment: A warning: removing objects from a list while you're iterating over it may skip some items! You might want to create a new list, rather than modifying an existing one.

Comment: @Blckknght Or iterate over a reversed list.

Comment: @SteinarLima: Heh, I was just about to edit my comment to mention reverse iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by looking at the code. Like you said, both functions are *nearly identical*. What's the only difference in the two functions? The attribute (`c.color` vs `c.engine`):

```
if car_n.color == c.color:
```

versus

```
if car_n.engine == c.engine:
```

Thus, you can change this code into this, using the builtin [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```
def rm_car_attribute(c, attrib):
    comparison_attrib = getattr(c, attrib)
    for car_n in cars[:]:
    # Blender mentioned a good practice: not to modify the list you are iterating
    # cars[:] creates a temporary copy of cars to iterate over
        try: 
            if getattr(car_n, attrib) == comparison_attrib:
                cars.remove(car_n)
        except Exception, err:
            pass
```

This can be used as such:

```
rm_car_attribute(c, 'engine') # same as rm_car_engine(c) from above
```

---

On another note, I'm not really sure what type of Exception you are expecting. The only possible error I see is if the car's attributes are explicitly defined (i.e `car_instance.engine = 'V8'`), but for one of the cars, the attribute is not defined (in your list of cars, one of the instances does not have an `engine` attribute). You can change the `try`/`except` to specifically catch this error:

```
def rm_car_attribute(c, attrib):
        comparison_attrib = getattr(c, attrib)
        for car_n in cars[:]:
            try: 
                if getattr(car_n, attrib) == comparison_attrib:
                    cars.remove(car_n)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
```

Answer (score 2):

A better alternative would be to just use a filtering function:

```
def remove_cars(cars, predicate):
    for car in cars[:]:  # Don't iterate over and modify a list at the same time
        if predicate(car):
            cars.remove(car)
```

Or:

```
def remove_cars(cars, predicate):
    for car in filter(cars[:], predicate):
        cars.remove(car)
```

And then call it:

```
remove_cars(cars, lambda c: c.color == car.color)
```

Or more verbosely:

```
def f(c):
    return c.color == car.color

remove_cars(cars, f)
```

The benefit of a filtering function is that you can do much more than check properties for equality:

```
remove_car(cars, lambda c: c.engine.startswith('V'))
```

Also, it may be easier to just return a new list instead of modifying your old one:

```
def remove_cars(cars, predicate):
    result = []

    for car in cars:
        if not predicate(car):
            result.append(car)

    return result
```

But that's basically the builtin `filter` function.

Answer (score 1):

Since the there is only one line different between the two functions, I suggest you pass a another function that will do the evaluation for you and then remove the car if it evaluates to `True`.

```
def rm_car_by_attr(c, func):
    # create a tmp list so you can iterate and remove at the same time
    tmp_cars_list = list(cars) 
    for car_n in tmp_cars_list:
        try:
            if func(car_n, c):
                cars.remove(car_n)
        except Exception, err:
            pass

def is_car_engine_the_same(car1, car2):
      return car1.engine == car2.engine

def is_car_color_the_same(car1, car2):
      return car1.color == car2.color

rm_car_by_attr(this_car, is_car_engine_the_same)
rm_car_by_attr(this_car, is_car_color_the_same)
```

Answer (score 0):

consider changing your data structure, perhaps use a [dict](http://docs.python.org/2.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to store key value pairs, then you can simply pass in your comparison type. Below code is untested, but should help you get the idea

```
car1.attributes['engine'] = 'V8'

def rm_car(c, remWhat):
    for car_n in cars:
        try:
            if car_n.attributes[remWhat] == c.attributes[remWhat]:
                cars.remove(car_n)
        except Exception, err:
            pass
```